# Pass query parameters through local response

Tags: 9

I'm trying to pass query parameters received on a controller from an external redirect through TrustedRedirectResponse or LocalRedirectResponse. None of the options seem to be working.

Comment: Probably need to see some code to comment further.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, we need to see the code you wrote so far. In this way, the answers could eventually point out what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Seeing the code would also help to understand what _seems to be working_ exactly means. Generally speaking, _it doesn't work_ isn't a much helpful phrase, in a question. Questions should make clear what exactly the issue is, or what exactly the OP doesn't understand in achieving the task described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receive the query parameters through the request you've added as parameter to the controller and pass them via the URL of the redirect.

Caching is a bit tricky because generating an absolute local URL bubbles up cacheable metadata which you need to collect by [Url::toString(TRUE)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/9.1.x):

```
public function view(Request $request) {

  $url = Url::fromRoute(
    '<front>', 
    [], 
    [
      'query' => $request->query->all(),
      'absolute' => TRUE,
    ]
  )->toString(TRUE);

  $redirect = new LocalRedirectResponse($url->getGeneratedUrl());
  $redirect->addCacheableDependency($url);
  $redirect->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheContexts(['url.query_args']);

  return $redirect;
}
```